# What's the most straightforward way to organize Win32 window controls?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am currently trying to learn the Win32 API to develop native GUI programs for Windows 10/11. These will be used as basic tools containing labels, text boxes, buttons, drop-down menus, and menu bars. I am currently writing C++ wrappers around all of the basic Win32 objects such as ATOM and HWND when creating classes and windows respectively.

I have been able to make a basic window with 2 buttons that resize when resizing the window. Moving forward, I want to be able to organize "widgets" (name of my abstraction class) automatically using horizontal and vertical layout boxes. From my research, it appears that "STATIC" class windows perform the containerization that I require and can even be suited to stylize a container if needed.

Here is the diagrams I have created to show the look of the window & parental hierarchy I tried implementing:
[image: parent illustration]

I have come across two problems:

1. If I make the buttons the children of the frame, the buttons do not inherit the font of the main parent window and do not pass WM_COMMAND messages when pressed.
2. If I make the buttons the children of the window, the frame gets periodically drawn over the buttons.

I would prefer to take the first approach but it seems to break the default functionality of the API. What is the most straightforward, traditional way to go about this? This question is not asking about recommendation for libraries.

Comment: My answer would be don't use this (WinApi) way of build ui's. Use something like WPF or Qt to develop applications. And this shows that you will likely get opinion based answers when you ask a "what is the best way..." question. (which is outside the scope of this forum).

Comment: @PepijnKramer I've already attempted using GTK (GTKmm more specifically) to build UIs and it wasn't awful but the reliance on XML to format UI elements was really not appealing, and it also did not look native. Qt and others required a metacompiler that wasn't compatible with my workflow. I am not hating WinAPI right now but I want some guidance. Google results are kinda sparse on specifics.

Comment: The part about being able to design your UI fully seperate of the actual code that needs to run might need some getting used too but it is really the best way (at least for bigger projects).  About the winapi version I have used it in the past and it is very tedious in its own way. Have you looked at MFC it already provides wrappers like CWnd, CButton etc...

Comment: @PepijnKramer I cannot use Visual Studio or Microsoft compilers due to license restrictions. I'm currently using MSYS2, Mingw, GCC, and CMake to compile this project and I think it would be difficult to use MFC with that even if I wanted to.

Comment: @dylanweber you can still use some parts of Qt (basically most of QWidgets and core stuff) which are licensed under LGPL, so long as you dynamically link to them, otherwise there is WxWidgets which is entirely LGPL, you don't want to program in Win32 directly, as you won't be able to make your app cross-platform, and you will reinvent a lot of things.

Comment: @AhmedAEK I've already explained why Qt doesn't work for my use case, and WxWidgets requires a lot of macros as well. Cross-platform is not applicable for this project as it is Windows only.

Comment: @dylanweber the requirement of windows only will change with the first customer that asks "can i run this on Mac ?", you don't want to be the one explaining to management that this is simply not possible because of your bad choices, anyway WxWidgets does provide a lot of the functionality that you are asking for (dynamic sizing and messages translation to events, and native windows look, C++ types), so it will make your life a lot easier, unless you want to rewrite the event system yourself to fix your current problem, and it does have modern constructs like binding evets at runtime.

Comment: "I cannot use Visual Studio or Microsoft compilers due to license restrictions." is quite fundamental to your question, you should put it in there as it changes everything. The problem with this is they are not up to date with Microsoft's SDK. If you hadn't say that I would have proposed to use WinUI3/WinAppSDK which is the modern way of doing this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/ not sure you can do this (easily?) w/o Visual Studio and/or MSVC.

Comment: What licence restrictions? The Visual Studio community edition has quite broad terms.

Comment: @SimonMourier Using WinUI3 without Visual Studio is primarily an exercise in reverse engineering. The [Windows App SDK team has also yet to deliver on their promise of WinUI 3 source code, making it difficult for the community to pick up this work](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/pull/1836#issuecomment-1555946508). Not even the Windows App SDK is [available to native developers](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/issues/2153#issuecomment-1312786179). WinUI3/WAS are .NET/C# only in practice. Feel free to make your voice heard if you wish to see that changed.

Comment: @IInspectable - Alas, my voice is not really heard, not sure whose voice is... I participated to WinUI3 community call 2 years ago but they didn"t really listen or even list the feedback points. The Microsoft team has changed a lot in 3 years, the open source promise seems quite dead (it re-uses lots of 100% internal Windows stuff DirectWrite, DirectComposition, Xaml, etc. I guess that's the problem). It's not total disaster, but actually I'm suprised by the small effort put in that technology (I do believe in it) with regards to the importance it has and what it could/should be.

Comment: @JonathanPotter My use case would fall under an "enterprise" in the Visual Studio Community license terms.

Comment: Due to some of your license restrictions, some modern ways don't work for your use case. Whether multiple-document interface (MDI) is the effect you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the desired font via `WM_SETFONT` on each individual control. A control does not inherit the font of its parent window.

`WM_COMMAND` (and `WM_NOTIFY`) is sent by a child control to its immediate parent window, so the parent's `WndProc` needs to handle the message. That means if the button is a child of a frame, the frame needs to handle the button's notifications.

Since you are designing your own class framework, consider having a parent `WndProc` reflect child-generated messages back to the child window that sent them, so that child's `WndProc` can handle its own notifications.

Your frame can appear on top of another control if they both have the same parent and the frame is higher on the z-order than the control.

Comment: I see where in my abstraction the passing along of fonts broke, so hopefully that can resolve the problem there. Furthermore, I see what you mean when you say that `WM_COMMAND` is only sent to it's immediate parent, but how would I set a `WndProc` on a window created with CreateWindow? Or should I use CreateWindowEx instead? What would the content of the `WndProc` look like to pass to *it's* parent?

Comment: For custom controls, a `WndProc` is specified via `RegisterClass/Ex()` before calling `CreateWindow/Ex()`. For standard OS controls, a `WndProc` can be assigned after `CreateWindow/Ex()` via `SetWindowLongPtr()` or `SetWindowSubclass()`

Answer (score -2):

1,the buttons do not inherit the font of the main parent window

You need to send `WM_SETFONT message` to set the font that a control is to use when drawing text.

2, do not pass WM_COMMAND messages when pressed.

When you click the button, the WM_COMMAND messages is sent to it's parent window (here is `Frame` not `parent window`). `WNDPROC` function is a callback function, which you define in your application, that processes messages sent to a window.

3,If I make the buttons the children of the window, the frame gets periodically drawn over the buttons.

As far as I'm concerned, you should make the buttons the children of the `Frame` not the `Parent Window`.

According to your description, It seems that you want to realize a multiple-document interface (MDI). If so, I suggest you could follow the Doc:[About the Multiple Document Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-the-multiple-document-interface)

Comment: Imagine suggesting MDI in 2023... And no, static controls and the controls they *visually* enclose should be **siblings**, not child/parent controls.